# WebApi Http Get does not work in HomeController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm learning Web Apis with Asp.Net MVC Core at the moment. I've tried the following simple code to get a return when I browse 'localhost\home\Test'. However 404 error comes out. Is there something I'm missing?

```
namespace JB.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("Test")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Test()
        {
            return new string[] { "Tvalue1", "Tvalue2" };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route template does not match the desired route.

Your expectation is based on a mixing of convention-based and attribute routing.

The current route template will map to `localhost/Test` based on the `Route` on the action.

Either update route template on action

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    //...code removed for brevity

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("home/Test")] //Maps GET home/test
    public IActionResult Test()  {
        var model = new string[] { "Tvalue1", "Tvalue2" };
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Or apply a route prefix on the controller

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller {

    //...code removed for brevity

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("Test")] //Maps GET home/test
    public IActionResult Test()  {
        var model = new string[] { "Tvalue1", "Tvalue2" };
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)